# Ruby local_to_utc returns invalid year

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, timezone, utc

I have the following date string ('US/Eastern'), which I need to convert to UTC:

```
date_src = '2014-07-07T23:10:00+0'
```

First I convert it to a "valid" format so I can operate it on later processes. I use the following to have an iso version of the date:

```
date = DateTime.parse(date_src).iso8601
```

At this point date is a nice `'2014-07-07T23:10:00+00:00'`. The last step on my  process is to translate this date to UTC. I'm using the following:

```
TZInfo::Timezone.get('US/Eastern').local_to_utc(date)
```

The problem is this is giving me **20014** as output, instead of the UTC version of the original date. If I try:

`TZInfo::Timezone.get('UTC').local_to_utc(date)`

I get **2014**, which is the correct year but still unexpected output.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong, and what I could use to solve the problem?

Comment: `+0` (or `+00:00`) would indicate UTC already... So how is that in `US/Eastern`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`local_to_utc`](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/blob/093bcd093cb52ff3c4d3f775e419af5074d17294/README.md#example-usage) actually expects a `Time` or a `DateTime` instance:

```
TZInfo::Timezone.get('US/Eastern').local_to_utc(DateTime.parse(date_src))
# => #<DateTime: 2014-07-08T03:10:00+00:00 ((2456847j,11400s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

From the documentation, you can have a hint on what actually happened:

> All methods in `TZInfo` that operate on a time can be used with either `Time` or `DateTime` instances or **with nteger timestamps (i.e. as returned by `Time#to_i`)**. The type of the values returned will match the the type passed in.

What actually happens is the `local_to_utc` calls `to_i` on the input parameter, which on a string returns the parsed integer from the beginning of the string (2014 in your case since `date` is the string `2014-07-07T23:10:00+00:00`), and adds the time difference to it - `18000` for "US/Eastern" (5 hour difference), and `0` for `UTC`:

```
date.to_i
# => 2014

TZInfo::Timezone.get('US/Eastern').local_to_utc(date) - date.to_i
# => 18000

TZInfo::Timezone.get('UTC').local_to_utc(date) - date.to_i
# => 0
```

So the bottom line is - kind of serendipitously you saw this weird behavior, which stems from the compilation of some surprising quirks of the APIs you used...

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for taking the time to write such an exhaustive explanation. "It all makes sense now" :)   Saludos desde Costa Rica.